# Excel VBA SaveAs "Read-only" PDF file

Tags: excel, vba, pdf

The following code successfully saves an excel sheet as PDF. I would like to save it as a file, that can be opened by everyone, but not edited with the "fill and sign" feature, that is provided by Adobe Acrobat Reader DC. I have tried to simply add the following, but that does not work:

```
Attributes:=vbReadOnly
```

Here is the rest of the code:

```
Dim sPath As String

sPath = "O:\"

With Worksheets("Sheet 1")
    .ExportAsFixedFormat _
        Type:=xlTypePDF, _
        Filename:=sPath & UserForm.TextBox1.Value & ".pdf", _
        Quality:=xlQualityStandard, _
        IncludeDocProperties:=True, _
        IgnorePrintAreas:=False, _
        OpenAfterPublish:=False
End With
```

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to use [`SetAttr`](https://learn.microsoft.com/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/setattr-statement) after saving.

```
SetAttr "c:\path\yourfilename.pdf", vbReadOnly
```

Comment: not working, I´m still able to fill&sign the pdf